# Is it possible to have different subnet for different VLAN in a L2switch?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, lan, switch, vlan

While creating the VLAN in L2 switch, is it possible for us to have diffetrent subnet for each VLAN? and for inter VLAN comunication can we use router(L2 switch)?

Comment: I thought that's pretty much the whole point of VLANs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very much so. I did this at work, using tag-based VLAN (802.1Q, if I remember correctly) to separate network hardware and wireless clients.

The gateway had a single physical connection to the master switch, but operated on both VLANs, which was reflected in the master switch config for that port. The gateway could therefor act as a router between the two VLANs for mantenance purposes.

How to do this depends a lot on your hardware, but to get back to your original question:

**Yes, it's possible**

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible (exact config depends on hardware), such configuration is commonly refered to as 'router on the stick' (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-armed_router)

Answer (score 0):

In a L2 switch each VLAN is a fully isolated LAN. For inter VLAN communication you will need an external equipment (router or L3 switch) connected to both VLANs.